# How to apply an automatic discount in WooCommerce based on cart total?

Tags: woocommerce, discount, coupon

Referring to this question [How do I programmatically apply a coupon in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744689/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-coupon-in-woocommerce?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'm looking for something very similar to the final solution in the first post, but I'd like the coupon to be applied if the subtotal is > 99 euros.

How do you think I can modify the code? And since I'm a newbie... where do I have to paste the whole code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be done:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_process','add_discount_at_checkout');

function add_discount_at_checkout(){
global $woocommerce;
$minorder = 99;
if( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart()->cart_contents_total>$minorder){

 //APPLY COUPON HERE

}
}
```

So basically, if your cart total is greater than 99, you can do something, like add a coupon.