# How to apply coupons to CoCart plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using **CoCart** plugin with **WooCommerce**. I have a `cart` with products and the plugin counts me the `totals` and actually everything. I would like to apply coupons, I made a plugin for this, but I had no idea how to get the cart which had been initialized with CoCart. I tried this: `WC()->session->get( 'cart_totals' )` and this: `WC()->cart`, but in both cases the `session` and `cart` is `null`. So I need a solution to make it possible to get the previously created cart.

Comment: Which version of CoCart are you using? Lite or Pro? Only CoCartPro has the functionality to support Coupons. See [features](https://cocart.xyz/features/) page and [documentation](https://docs.cocart.xyz/pro.html#coupons-applied-coupons) for pro. 

If you have the lite version, you might have to go through their documentation to figure out if there is indeed a place for you to extend this functionality.

Comment: I am using the Lite version. And this is what I want to make it possible to apply coupons with this version too.

Comment: Well, in that case, you will have to look at the CoCart Lite's code to see if there is even a possibility to achieve such a thing. Although I highly doubt that they would have such a functionality in place.

Comment: Why did you decide to not award the bounty when you chose to accept the Answer?

Answer (score 1):

a mildly different Solution is discussed in this thread, have a look. below is the excerpt copied from there. the question was initially asked by **msargenttrue** and answered by **Freney**

the post suggests that you need to do a manual implementation in PHP which is just copypaste , and call the script to apply on the intended product in database. [THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744689/apply-a-coupon-programmatically-in-woocommerce?rq=1) <-- the PHP implementation part

FOR the problem

> So I need a solution to make it possible to get the previously created
> cart.

you must try the js implementation of local storage, the stored item remains on the user device until the cart is cleared explicitly.

```
localStorage.setItem("cart", "CartID-002");
localStorage.clear() #when you want to remove.
```

Points to remember
The main features of localStorage are:

1. Shared between all tabs and windows from the same origin.
2. The data does not expire. It remains after the browser restart and
   even OS reboot.